# Failed to start LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API

Tags: centos, libvirt, cobbler

I am trying to install cobber(https://cobbler.github.io/) in centos VM.

when I tried to start cobbler , libvirtd fails to start message thrown.

```
[root@dev cobbler]# systemctl start cobblerd
Job for cobblerd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cobblerd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

cobblerd.service log

```
[root@dev cobbler]# systemctl status cobblerd.service
● cobblerd.service - LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cobblerd; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-24 04:30:55 PDT; 7s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1615 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/cobblerd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 24 04:30:54 dev systemd[1]: Starting LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API...
May 24 04:30:55 dev cobblerd[1615]: Starting cobbler daemon: [FAILED]
May 24 04:30:55 dev systemd[1]: cobblerd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 24 04:30:55 dev systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API.
May 24 04:30:55 dev systemd[1]: Unit cobblerd.service entered failed state.
May 24 04:30:55 dev systemd[1]: cobblerd.service failed.
```

Below is the logs of journalctl -xe

```
[root@dev ~]# systemctl start cobblerd
Job for cobblerd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cobblerd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@dev ~]# journalctl -xe
Jun 03 19:58:34 ztp-dev sshd[29992]: Failed password for invalid user support from 104.99.0.147 port 56131 ssh2
Jun 03 19:58:34 ztp-dev sshd[29992]: Connection reset by 104.99.0.147 port 56131 [preauth]
Jun 03 19:58:36 ztp-dev sshd[29994]: Did not receive identification string from 104.99.0.147 port 56418
Jun 03 19:58:45 ztp-dev polkitd[5598]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:29996:625961854 (system bus name :1.3601 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fall
Jun 03 19:58:45 ztp-dev systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jun 03 19:58:45 ztp-dev polkitd[5598]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:29996:625961854 (system bus name :1.3601, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit
Jun 03 19:59:21 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: Invalid user demo from 125.207.14.76 port 47714
Jun 03 19:59:21 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: input_userauth_request: invalid user demo [preauth]
Jun 03 19:59:21 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun 03 19:59:21 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=125.207.14.76
Jun 03 19:59:23 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: Failed password for invalid user demo from 125.207.14.76 port 47714 ssh2
Jun 03 19:59:23 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: Received disconnect from 125.207.14.76 port 47714:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 03 19:59:23 ztp-dev sshd[30017]: Disconnected from 125.207.14.76 port 47714 [preauth]
Jun 03 20:00:09 ztp-dev sshd[30022]: Did not receive identification string from 219.92.1.132 port 57163
Jun 03 20:00:17 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: Address 25.95.113.42 maps to host.colocrossing.com, but this does not map back to the address - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jun 03 20:00:17 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: Invalid user raynard from 25.95.113.42 port 52350
Jun 03 20:00:17 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: input_userauth_request: invalid user raynard [preauth]
Jun 03 20:00:17 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun 03 20:00:17 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=25.95.113.42
Jun 03 20:00:19 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: Failed password for invalid user raynard from 25.95.113.42 port 52550 ssh2
Jun 03 20:00:19 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: Received disconnect from 25.95.113.42 port 52350:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 03 20:00:19 ztp-dev sshd[30023]: Disconnected from 25.95.113.42 port 52350 [preauth]
Jun 03 20:00:28 ztp-dev polkitd[5598]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:30025:625972177 (system bus name :1.3602 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fall
Jun 03 20:00:28 ztp-dev systemd[1]: Starting LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API...
-- Subject: Unit cobblerd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit cobblerd.service has begun starting up.
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev cobblerd[30031]: Starting cobbler daemon: [FAILED]
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev systemd[1]: cobblerd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: daemon for libvirt virtualization API.
-- Subject: Unit cobblerd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit cobblerd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev systemd[1]: Unit cobblerd.service entered failed state.
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev systemd[1]: cobblerd.service failed.
Jun 03 20:00:29 ztp-dev polkitd[5598]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:30025:625972177 (system bus name :1.3602, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit
```

I could able to start libvirtd like below.

```
[root@dev cobbler]# systemctl status libvirtd
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-05-24 04:09:21 PDT; 20min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 789 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 19 (limit: 32768)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           ├─  789 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
           ├─29627 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
           └─29628 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper

May 24 04:09:21 dev systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
May 24 04:09:21 dev systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
May 24 04:09:21 dev dnsmasq[29627]: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses
May 24 04:09:21 dev dnsmasq[29627]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 addresses
May 24 04:09:21 dev dnsmasq-dhcp[29627]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
```

I could able to start/stop libvirt using systemctl start/stop libvirt command, but libvirtd fails to start when run the systemctl start cobblerd

How to address this issue?

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: Check cobbler's log files.

Comment: have you notice this? **Job for cobblerd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cobblerd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
** add those logs to your question.

Comment: Hi @asktyagi ,added logs of the journalctl -xe and systemctl status cobblerd.service in the question, thanks Mohan